# Composing Nested Observables with Dependencies in RxJava

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm writing a small application to familiarize myself with the FRP paradigm and RxJava.

I have two methods; `getUsers()` and `getNextTask(userId)`. These methods return `Observable<User>` and `Observable<Task>` respectively and getNextTask depends on User items emitted from getUsers Observable.

I have written the following code which combines the results of the two calls into one object, `UserSummary`, using `flatMap()`:

```
getUsers()
  .flatMap(u -> (Observable<UserSummary>) getNextTask(u.getId()).map(t -> new UserSummary(u, t))
  .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

This code works fine and emits the values that I expect, however, I expected values of type `UserSummary` and instead received values of type `Object` which I then cast to `UserSummary`.

My question is, is `flatMap()` a good place to call `getNextTask()` or is there perhaps a more effective method of calling methods with dependencies?

**Edit**

With regards to the `flatMap` returning `Observable<Object>` instead of `Observable<UserSummary>` as I would have expected of a generic method, the following quick snippet illustrates the problem. The flatMap operator is expected to return `Observable<String>`, however it returns `Observable<Object>`. Therefore, returns have to be cast to their respective types.

```
Integer[] numberArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Observable.from(numberArray)
  .flatMap(i -> {
    String[] letterArray = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
    return Observable.from(letterArray)
      .map(x -> x + i);
  }).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: That's the best place to use `flatMap`. BTW, where is the `cast`?

Comment: Thank you @zsxwing, I added the cast to the function in `flatMap`, thanks for pointing that out. I did some more reading in the mean time and found some RxJS snippets that use flatMap in a similar way.

Comment: I tried in 1.8.0_20 and the codes can be compiled without the cast.

Comment: Yes the code works perfectly... It's more of a pet peeve; if I remove the cast in flatMap, I either have to use `map(o -> (UserSummary) o)` or cast the Object to UserSummary in the subscribe onNext() call so that I can access member variables etc.

Comment: Could you provide an simple example for me to reproduce the error? Maybe the problem is in the signatures of `getUsers` and `getNextTask`.

Comment: The problem persists with even simpler code... I've updated the question with a snippet that uses basic arrays whereby the value received in subscribe() should be a String, but is an Object.

Comment: I can compile your example. Which version of JDK are you using? Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508223/when-returning-a-list-of-custom-objects-rxjava-highlights-an-error-but-compiles

Comment: I posted a wrong link. Already updated it.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be a better solution. I'm using 1.8.0_20.