# When returning a List of custom Objects RxJava highlights an error but compiles

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm making an RxJava call and the end result I subscribe to is a List of Booking.

The code works fine but I get this annoying highlight:

[image]

A cast doesn't work here because I can't cast `List <Booking>` to `List <Object>`.

Ok, you might say I should just replace it with a lambda expression, but in the `call()` method I need to call a method that takes `List <Booking>` as a parameter:

[image]

How can I avoid highlighting in any of these cases?

Comment: cast your List<Object> to List<Booking> ?

Comment: Try use `flatMap` like this `<Booking>flatMap`. Sometimes Java 8 type inference doesn't work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an explicit type to the generic methods, such as `<Booking>flatMap`. Sometimes Java 8 type inference doesn't work well.